# codeigniter calls none of the functions of a specific controller while works fine with others

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, controller

I am using CodeIgniter 2.2;

a while ago i created a site with codeigniter (following the codeigniter dynamic data tutorial)  and made two controllers (along with their models of course) namely, suggestions and reports. And as for the first need i made the create functions and views for both of these controllers. and they were all working fine both in my local (windows, MySQL) and remote (linux, MySQL). However, yesterday, i tried to add the view functions and listing the values in my database too. I added the simple view functions

```
$data['suggestions'] = $this->suggestions_model->get_suggestions();
$this->load->view('suggestions/view',$data);
```

and for reports the same

```
$data['reports'] = $this->reports_model->get_reports();
$this->load->view('reports/view',$data);
```

This works fine at my local and i can see the results for both of them. However, when i put it to the production (remote) suggestions controller works with its create and view functions but reports controller doesnt return anything. Now also  the create function of reports controller doesnt work. it too, simply returns empty html and no errors. I placed "echo" and "var_dump()" commands to several places including the constructor of the reports controller. However, it simply returns nothing with no error message. (As it is the production environment, php errors might have been closed (i am not the admin)) So, what can be the cause of this, and for a solution where do i need to take a look? or simply what is the solution?

PS : I have edited the index.php as suggested below and this is my error message : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /my_site/application/controllers/reports.php on line 37

and line 37 is : $data['reports'] = $this->reports_model->get_reports();

It looks all fine, but what is the problem? And for those who ask about it, yes i load the model in constructor...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Check out my index.php

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            // Report all errors
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            // Display errors in output
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            // Report all errors except E_NOTICE
            // This is the default value set in php.ini
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

            // Don't display errors (they can still be logged)
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it is just a typo.. it is correct in my php files.. i just didnt copy and paste the codes :)

Comment: Are you sure that the reports folder exists in the view folder of the server? I know this is trivial though. And that there is a view.php under that folder?

Comment: if i didnt have it, it would simply give content not found 404 error. but all the files are there, and they are exactly where they should be.

Comment: It should report all error for development, not production. For testing production you have to edit it accordingly to use  ini_set('display_errors', 1); for production as well.

Comment: thank you, i did it and now i have :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /my_site/application/controllers/reports.php on line 37

Comment: and this is line 37 : $data['reports'] = $this->reports_model->get_reports();

Comment: How do you load this model exactly? Show us code :D

Comment: in the constructor :)  public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();



  $this->load->model('reports_model');
  $this->load->library("session");
  $this->load->helper('url');
  session_start();
  

echo "Başarı ile oluşturuldu";

 }

and it doesnt echo anything :)

Comment: You should know that "reports_model" is case sensitive. Other than that you will have to debug why it does echo anything... put another echo at the beginning of the constructor...

Comment: i am sure the cases match :) and after putting echo "Sucess"; line before, after and "before and after" the line  parent::__construct(); still nothing changed.. :( the same error..

Comment: My friend I guess that this question serves no purpose now that the first issue (of not seeing the error) is resolved. You should accept whichever answer you wish and maybe start a new question or try to debug the code. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
   Missed out the closing "'" for first parameter. Copy the below code and try.

   $this->load->view('suggestions/view',$data);
   $this->load->view('reports/view',$data);
```

Comment: unfortunately it is just a typo.. it is correct in my php files.. i just didnt copy and paste the codes :)

Comment: As you have specified that it is working in local windows server, can you please check the name of the classes and folders with case sensitive. Linux is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in index.php, maybe you can get php errors to show:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: And check config/database.php: if the environment is production, the mysql credentials might be different and you might not have a mysql connection.

Comment: db configs are all fine... i double checked :)